# Behavior of var

Tags: c#, .net

```
DataTable test = new DataTable();
foreach (var r in test.Rows)
{
    r[1].tostring();
}
```

Why doesn't the compiler understand that r is a DataRow?
See the below image for the error message.

[image]

Comment: What type does test.Rows return?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The property [`DataTable.Rows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) uses an older style (non-generic) collection.  The actual type is [`DataRowCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) which defines [an enumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135386(v=vs.110).aspx) that is non-generic so it returns instances of type `object`.  To address this problem a new extension method was provided in later versions of the framework (3.5+) called [`DataTable.AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) that returns a properly-typed enumerator:

```
DataTable test = new DataTable();
foreach (var r in test.AsEnumerable())
{
    r[1].ToString();
}
```

If you are stuck on an older version of .NET you would have to cast `r` to `DataRow` manually.

Answer (score 1):

The Type of `DataTable.Rows` is `DataRowCollection` which inherits from `InternalDataCollectionBase`, which inherits from `ICollection`, the non-generic one. So it is *not* an `ICollection<DataRow>`, but a collection of `objects`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
With `foreach (DataRow r in test.Rows)`, you are explicitly telling C# to cast each object to a `DataRow`

Answer (score 0):

var is an implicit type ! It aliases any type! When you declare a "var type" you are basically telling the compiler hey look I don't know what type is appropriate for this so whatever type the expression on the right evaluates to that is the appropriate type!

So,
     Here obviously each row is returned as an object so unless you cast them to the appropriate type they will remain as an object!